# Connect powered speakers to powered mixer?

Tags: mixer, power

I would like to know if it isn't dangerous to connect a pair of speakers (Edifier r1000tc power supplied) to Beringher PMH2000 (power mixer).

Comment: hi, this is rather of topic for a sound design site. however you are welcome to ask design related questions in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find any other StackExchange Sound forum.

Comment: No problem, perhaps there is non. Good luck with your trouble. You could also check sites like gearslutz.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly safe, you just need to use the mixer as if it weren't powered at all, i.e. not use the Speakon ports but the unpowered 1/4" line-outs.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Ok sounds right. The speakon inputs would need a rare adapter so I was about to connect it using rca cable into the rca outputs from the front. So the fact that it is a powered mixer wouldn't damage the Edifier speakers?

Comment: @redraw: no. If you used the Speakon outputs with adaptors it would probably cause horrible clipping distortion of the speakers' inputs, but even that shouldn't damage them permanently. But the line-outs on a powered mixer work exactly the same as on an unpowered mixer, so these will work _just fine_ with active speakers.

Comment: Note that while on your specific mixer, it is only the NL2 speakon connectors on the back that are powered, some powered mixers may have powered 1/4" jacks as well.  It is important to make sure that you never send a powered signal to a device expecting line level (such as a powered speaker input).

Comment: Ok. @AJHenderson but my powered mixer doesn't have powered 1/4'' (RCA), right? Now you let me think about it.

Comment: It has a special MONITOR output too. http://www.behringer.com/assets/PMH2000_P0065_M_EN.pdf

Comment: @redraw - correct, you don't have powered 1/4" on that behringer as far as I can tell.  Note that RCA is not 1/4" either.  RCA is phono plugs (white and red) like for a VCR.  1/4" is like a large headphone jack.  You would want to use the 1/4" to go to a set of powered speakers, the RCA connectors are generally designed for going to a CD Recorder or tape deck.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused about RCA and 1/4'' plug. My powered mixer really is PMH2000, I've edited my question. It does have "Preamp - Monitor" output, so that should be the best way to connect the Edifier active monitors.
However, it is also fine to use the RCA outputs I guess

Comment: @Redraw - if you use the RCA outputs, there will likely be an impedance mismatch.  RCA jacks often don't have the same impedance as a 1/4" preamp output.  This could potentially cause noise, low signal, or clipping depending on which way the impedance mismatches.